# List comprehension for Pythagorean Triples

Tags: python

I am new to Python and would like to learn how to use list comprehension.

I have this code that prints a list of Pythagorean Triples less than the user-input value `n`:

```
n = int(input("Enter the value of n:"))

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
m = 2
triples = []

while c < n:
    for i in range(1, m, 1):
        a = m*m - i*i
        b = 2*m*i
        c = m*m + i*i
        if c > n:
            break
        triples.append((a, b, c))
    m += 1

print(triples)
```

It kinda works but I want to do the same using list comprehension in Python how can we do that?

For example if I input 17 the output should be `[(3,4,5), (8,6,10),(5,12,13), (15,8,17), (9,12,15)]` however I am not getting `(9,12,15)`.

Comment: This sequence will never generate `(9, 12, 15)` for any value of `n`. You need to completely change your triples-generating logic.

Comment: In any case, you're asking two distinct questions. One is about list comprehensions and the other is why your triples generator fails to generate all possible triples.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I used this tutorial is the tutorial wrong ? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-pythagorean-triplets

Comment: Did you read the note in the tutorial, "The above method doesn’t generate all triplets smaller than a given limit. For example “9 12 15” which is a valid triplet is not printed by above method"? This is exactly the case you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [**official python documentation for list comprehensions**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) it explains how they work really well.

As for your actual question, the following should be an equivalent list comprehension to print the [**Pythagorean triples**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple) up til `n`:

```
n = int(input('Enter the value of n: '))
print([(a, b, c) for a in range(1, n + 1) for b in range(a, n + 1)
       for c in range(b, n + 1) if a**2 + b**2 == c**2])
```

Hopefully, it is clear to you what the issue is in your current code :)

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter the value of n: 17
[(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15)]
```

---

**Edit: A more efficient version that utilizes [Python 3.8's walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):**

```
import math

n = int(input('Enter the value of n: '))
print([(a, b, int(c)) for a in range(1, n + 1) for b in range(a, n + 1)
       if (c := math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)) % 1 == 0 and c <= n])
```

Comment: can more efficient by removing c in range part as below such that only two ranges are used
a = range(1,101)
[(i,j,math.sqrt(i*i+j*j)) for i in a for j in a if math.sqrt(i*i+j*j)%1==0]

Comment: @michael Is my edit the same logic as what you described?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools`. Try this -

```
import itertools

n = int(input("Enter the value of n:"))

print([(a,b,c) for a, b, c in itertools.product(range(1,n+1), repeat=3) if a**2 + b**2 == c**2])
```

To know more about `itertools` and `product` follow this link -
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Using `product` we get a tuple of 3 elements which we unpack to three variables a, b, c and used comprehension to include only those tuple which satisfies the if condition.

This code however generates duplicates like (3,4,5) and (4,3,5)

To remove the duplicates you can easily modify the if statement like this -

```
print([(a,b,c) for a, b, c in itertools.product(range(1,n+1), repeat=3) if a < b < c and a**2 + b**2 == c**2])
```

This modified code will get you following output for `n=17` -

```
[(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15)]
```